# Extracting specific files from ZIP in PHP

Tags: php, zip, extract

If I have a ZIP file whose structure is:

```
  -directory1 DIR
      -files in here
  -directory2 DIR
      -more files in here
```

Using pclzip.lib.php how can I open up this ZIP file and extract directory1 (recursive) into a directory and then extract directory2 (recursive) into another directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the PCLZIP_OPT_BY_NAME option to select which path inside the archive you want to extract.  PCLZIP_OPT_PATH ought to determine where that branch will be written.

But that's just a guess after browsing [the manual](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/55) -- I've never used this particular library.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test_im.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('directory1', array('item.gif', 'file1.php'));
    $zip->extractTo('directory2', array('item1.gif', 'file2.php'));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is an example of the zip extension, it's not pclzip.