# Extract sub folders of ZIP file in PHP

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I am using a php script to unzip ZIP file. but this script unzip only one level of directories without extracting  the sub directories of that file
the script:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

for example: if the test.zip contains 2 folders: folder1\file.png, folder2\folder3\file3.png

after extracting this ZIP file, i only see the folder1*.* and folder2*.* but without the sub directory folder3.

How can i improve it?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707050/377628?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this PHP manual will be helpful to you
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php

```
<?php
$file = "2537c61ef7f47fc3ae919da08bcc1911.zip";
$dir = getcwd();
function Unzip($dir, $file, $destiny="")
{
    $dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $path_file = $dir . $file;
    $zip = zip_open($path_file);
    $_tmp = array();
    $count=0;
    if ($zip)
    {
        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
        {
            $_tmp[$count]["filename"] = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
            $_tmp[$count]["stored_filename"] = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
            $_tmp[$count]["size"] = zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry);
            $_tmp[$count]["compressed_size"] = zip_entry_compressedsize($zip_entry);
            $_tmp[$count]["mtime"] = "";
            $_tmp[$count]["comment"] = "";
            $_tmp[$count]["folder"] = dirname(zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
            $_tmp[$count]["index"] = $count;
            $_tmp[$count]["status"] = "ok";
            $_tmp[$count]["method"] = zip_entry_compressionmethod($zip_entry);

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r"))
            {
                $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
                if($destiny)
                {
                    $path_file = str_replace("/",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $destiny . zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
                }
                else
                {
                    $path_file = str_replace("/",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dir . zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
                }
                $new_dir = dirname($path_file);

                // Create Recursive Directory (if not exist)  
                if (!file_exists($new_dir)) {
                  mkdir($new_dir, 0700);
                }

                $fp = fopen($dir . zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
                fwrite($fp, $buf);
                fclose($fp);

                zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
            }
            echo "\n</pre>";
            $count++;
        }

        zip_close($zip);
    }
}
Unzip($dir,$file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This script extracts all files in the zip file recursively. This will extract them into the current directory.

```
    <?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    echo "HI<br><br>";
    //----------------
    //UNZIP a zip file
    //----------------

    $zipfilename = "site.zip";

    //----------------

    function unzip($file){

        $zip=zip_open(realpath(".")."/".$file);
        if(!$zip) {return("Unable to proccess file '{$file}'");}

        $e='';

        while($zip_entry=zip_read($zip)) {
           $zdir=dirname(zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
           $zname=zip_entry_name($zip_entry);

           if(!zip_entry_open($zip,$zip_entry,"r")) {$e.="Unable to proccess file '{$zname}'";continue;}
           if(!is_dir($zdir)) mkdirr($zdir,0777);

           #print "{$zdir} | {$zname} \n";

           $zip_fs=zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry);
           if(empty($zip_fs)) continue;

           $zz=zip_entry_read($zip_entry,$zip_fs);

           $z=fopen($zname,"w");
           fwrite($z,$zz);
           fclose($z);
           zip_entry_close($zip_entry);

        }
        zip_close($zip);

        return($e);
    }

    function mkdirr($pn,$mode=null) {

      if(is_dir($pn)||empty($pn)) return true;
      $pn=str_replace(array('/', ''),DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$pn);

      if(is_file($pn)) {trigger_error('mkdirr() File exists', E_USER_WARNING);return false;}

      $next_pathname=substr($pn,0,strrpos($pn,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
      if(mkdirr($next_pathname,$mode)) {if(!file_exists($pn)) {return mkdir($pn,$mode);} }
      return false;
    }

    unzip($zipfilename);

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple way:

```
system('unzip my_zip_file.zip');
```