# Unzip sub directory using PHP

Tags: php, compression, zip, unzip, php-ziparchive

I have a zip file with sub directories inside it. I use the php `extractTo()` function to unzip it, but I only get the files from the root, I can't get the files inside the subdirectories.

My Zip file has this structure:

```
-Json
  - 01.json
  - 02.json
  - 03.json
  - URL
     - url1.json
     - url2.json
  - seeker
     - seek1.json
     - seek.json
```

And my code is:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($nombrezip);
$zip->extractTo($destino);
$zip->close();
```

So I need to Unzip the files inside "URL" and "seeker".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract sub folders of ZIP file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968359/extract-sub-folders-of-zip-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have a ZipFile: *test.zip*

Structure:

```
- file1.txt
- file1.txt
- - dir1/
- - - file3.txt
- - - file4.txt
- - dir2/
- - - file5.txt
- - - file6.txt
```

To keep ZIP structure you could do:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('./test', array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt'));
    $zip->extractTo('./test', array('dir1/file3.txt', 'dir1/file4.txt'));
    $zip->extractTo('./test', array('dir2/file5.txt', 'dir2/file6.txt'));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

**That's the same as doing**

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('./test');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

But if you have a *test.zip* file with this Structure:

```
- file1.txt
- file1.txt
- file3.txt
- file4.txt
- file5.txt
- file6.txt
```

And you want to get output structured as before, you could do this:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('./test/', array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt'));
    $zip->extractTo('./test/dir1', array('file3.txt', 'file4.txt'));
    $zip->extractTo('./test/dir2', array('file5.txt', 'file6.txt'));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```